# Download older curl rpm's

Tags: linux, curl

How to download older curl rpm's? say version 7.20.0. I searched in https://curl.haxx.se, official site, they do not put up older versions

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link has all previous versions, from official site.

https://curl.haxx.se/download/